# ASP.NET MVC: Passing items through to home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently building an application that has a to-do list function. And I am trying to pass through items to my home page through the home controller that have a due date in the next two weeks. The following code is in the HomeController.

```
   MembershipUser myObject = Membership.GetUser();
   Guid UserID = (Guid)myObject.ProviderUserKey;

   DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
   dateTime = DateTime.Now;
   dateTime.AddDays(14);

   var model = db.Task.Where(n => n.UserId == UserID).Where(x => x.Due < dateTime);
   return View(model);
```

The following code is in the Home Index View:

```
   <ul class="upcoming">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <li>@item.Title</li>
   }
   </ul>
```

However, this returns every item in the Task table in the database, even ones over 2 weeks away. How can I fix this?

Many thanks,
Dale

Comment: Did you check the actual SQL queries that are sent to the database? Does the data in your database contain tasks whose due date is greater then two weeks?

Comment: I wanted to do that, but I couldn't figure out how. In SQL Server Management Studio? There are definitely items that match the query though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime.AddDays() returns a new DateTime object, it doesn't modify the instance. Try:

`var dateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);`

Comment: dateTime is already declared. dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(14); will suffice